# netsh command output logging in powershell

Tags: logging, powershell

The below script works fine and displays all the iformation I need - however, there is a problem in displaying NETSH commands. So, normally in powershell if you enter the below:

```
netsh int tcp show global
```

It displays in the TABLe format as below:

```
TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State          : disabled
Chimney Offload State               : disabled
NetDMA State                        : enabled
Direct Cache Acess (DCA)            : disabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : disabled
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : none
ECN Capability                      : disabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
```

However, when I do this in a powershell script that logs to a LOG file the output is all scewed - ie the below:

```
Querying active state...  TCP Global Parameters ---------------------------------------------- Receive-Side Scaling State          : disabled  Chimney Offload State               : disabled  NetDMA State                        : disabled  Direct Cache Acess (DCA)            : disabled  Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : disabled  Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : none  ECN Capability                      : disabled  RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
```

Any idea how I can keep the TABLE format that powershell command prompt displays?

Script:

```
 $computerdel = gc env:computername

 $t = "D:\temp\$(gc env:computername).log"
 #$e = Test-Path $t rm $t -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 #if ( $e -eq $true ) { rm $t }
 #else { Write-Host "Shortcut does not exist." }


 $Logfile = "D:\temp\$(gc env:computername).log"

 Function LogWrite {    Param ([string]$logstring)

    Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring }

 LogWrite
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 $Date = Get-Date

 LogWrite "Script has been run on $Date - This is Servers Local Time"
 LogWrite $computer = gc env:computername $onetcp = ((get-childitem
 c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductMajorPart).tostring()
 $twotcp = ((get-childitem
 c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductMinorPart).tostring()
 $threetcp = ((get-childitem
 c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductBuildPart).tostring()
 $fourtcp = ((get-childitem
 c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo.ProductPrivatePart).tostring()


 $onedfsr = ((get-childitem
 c:\windows\system32\dfsrs.exe).Versioninfo.ProductMajorPart).tostring()
 $twodfsr = ((get-childitem
 c:\windows\system32\dfsrs.exe).Versioninfo.ProductMinorPart).tostring()
 $threedfsr = ((get-childitem
 c:\windows\system32\dfsrs.exe).Versioninfo.ProductBuildPart).tostring()
 $fourdfsr = ((get-childitem
 c:\windows\system32\dfsrs.exe).Versioninfo.ProductPrivatePart).tostring()

 $hotfix1 = Get-HotFix -Id KB2450944 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 $hotfix2 = Get-HotFix -Id KB2582284 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 #$hotfix3 = Get-HotFix -Id KB979808 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 LogWrite

 If ($hotfix2) {    LogWrite "Hotfix KB2582284 is installed - This is
 TCPIP.sys Upgrade Hotfix" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor
 Black  } else {    LogWrite "Hotfix KB2582284 is NOT installed - Please
 ensure you install this hotfix - This is DFSRS.exe Upgrade Hotfix"
 -ForegroundColor "red"     }

 LogWrite "TCPIP.sys Version on $computer is:
 ""$onetcp.$twotcp.$threetcp.$fourtcp"" " LogWrite If ($hotfix1) {
    LogWrite "Hotfix KB2450944 is installed - This is DFSRS.exe Upgrade
 Hotfix" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black  } else {
    LogWrite "Hotfix KB2450944 is NOT installed - Please ensure you
 install this hotfix - This is DFSRS.exe Upgrade Hotfix"
 -ForegroundColor "red"     }    LogWrite "DFSRS.exe Version on $computer is: ""$onedfsr.$twodfsr.$threedfsr.$fourdfsr"" "

 LogWrite

 If (get-wmiobject win32_share | where-object {$_.Name -eq "REMINST"})
 {   LogWrite "The REMINST share exists on $computer" } Else {  
 LogWrite "The REMINST share DOES NOT exist on $computer - Please
 create as per standards"  }  

 #If ($hotfix3) {
 #  LogWrite "Hotfix KB979808 is installed" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
 #  }
 #else {
 #  LogWrite "Hotfix KB979808 is NOT installed - Please ensure you install this hotfix" -ForegroundColor "red"
 #}      LogWrite

 $u = "DBG\ADS-ALL-ROFS-Manager"; net localgroup "Distributed COM
 Users" | Where {$_ -match $u}

 If ($u) {  LogWrite "DBG\ADS-ALL-ROFS-Manager is part of Distributed
 COM Users localgroup on $computer"     } else {    LogWrite
 "DBG\ADS-ALL-ROFS-Manager is NOT part of Distributed COM Users
 localgroup on $computer"   } LogWrite $disabletaskoffload =
 Get-ItemProperty
 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters' -Name
 'DisableTaskOffload' | fl  DisableTaskOffload -ErrorAction
 SilentlyContinue $EnableTCPChimney = Get-ItemProperty
 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters' -Name
 'EnableTCPChimney' | fl  EnableTCPChimney $EnableTCPA =
 Get-ItemProperty
 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters' -Name
 'EnableTCPA' | fl  EnableTCPA $EnableRSS = Get-ItemProperty
 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters' -Name
 'EnableRSS' | fl  EnableRSS

 If ($disabletaskoffload) {     LogWrite "Registry Key DisableTaskOffload
 is set" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black  } else {
    LogWrite "Registry Key DisableTaskOffload is NOT set"
 -ForegroundColor "red"     }    If ($EnableTCPChimney) {   LogWrite "Registry Key EnableTCPChimney is set" -BackgroundColor Green
 -ForegroundColor Black     } else {    LogWrite "Registry Key EnableTCPChimney is NOT set" -ForegroundColor "red"  }    If
 ($EnableTCPA) {    LogWrite "Registry Key EnableTCPA is set"
 -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black  } else {    LogWrite "Registry Key EnableTCPA is NOT set" -ForegroundColor "red"    }    If
 ($EnableRSS) {     LogWrite "Registry Key EnableRSS is set"
 -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black  } else {    LogWrite "Registry Key EnableRSS is NOT set" -ForegroundColor "red"     } $netsh =
 netsh int tcp show global LogWrite LogWrite "***Running Netsh
 Check***" LogWrite "Ensure the following are set to disabled:"
 LogWrite "Receive-Side Scaling State: Disabled" LogWrite "Chimney
 Offload State: Disabled" LogWrite "Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level:
 Disabled" LogWrite LogWrite $netsh LogWrite
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you LogWrite function simply converts its input to a string and "dumps" it to the log file. The simplest solution for you would be to replace it with appending `| Out-File -Append <logfile>` to each post you want to put in the log:

```
>"Some message" | Out-File -Append <logfile>
>netsh int tcp show global | Select-Object -skip 2 | Out-File -Append <logfile>
```

will produce:

```
Some message
TCP Global Parameters
---------------------------------------------- 
Receive-Side Scaling State          : enabled
Chimney Offload State               : automatic
NetDMA State                        : enabled
Direct Cache Acess (DCA)            : disabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : normal
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : none
ECN Capability                      : disabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
```

(The `Select-Object` is a simple way to skip some beginning lines from output)

Comment: Thanks for that - and thanks for the edit Christian!

Sorry - trying to still figure out how to amend my script to show out-file. Shall I keep the code as it is and when I am running the script I just do a .\run.ps1 | out-file ... ?

Also, what does the Select-Object skip 2 bit do? 

Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I'd remove the `LogFile` function, and replace it with any of:
1) Remove the function call, and add `| Out-File ...` on each row. This way, the script will always write to the designated file. Or,
2) Simply use `Write-Output` in the script, then you can choose where the output should go; run the script as it is and get the output into console, or add `| Out-File ...` to the call to save to the log.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the "header/footer" lines with a simple regular expression that gets the lines that matches the colon character:

```
netsh int tcp show global | where {$_ -match ':'}
```